# Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, c, windows, dll, ctypes

I have tried to run an exemple of a python code that gets a function from a library  using ctypes. The exemple can be found [here](https://github.com/dvida/py-ctypes-multidimensional-arrays). I followed the instruction and beside one minor modification, I have used the exact same code. I have been trying to run this on Windows 10 (64-bit), python 3.7 (64-bit) but got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gifr9302/PycharmProjects/testpytoc/myfunc.py", line 128, in <module>
    libmyfunc = npct.load_library('myfunc.dll', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
  File "C:\Users\gifr9302\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py", line 152, in load_library
    return ctypes.cdll[libpath]
  File "C:\Users\gifr9302\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 431, in __getitem__
    return getattr(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\gifr9302\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\gifr9302\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide
```

translated:

`OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

I have tried to create a dll instead of a so file and still got the same error. It would seem it tries to run a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system but I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's an architecture mismatch problem. Either you have *32bit* *Python* trying to load a *64bit* *.dll*, or the other way around: *64bit* *Python* trying to load a *32bit* *.dll*.

Comment: Please include your code in the post. Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your post.

Comment: Yeah, it was a 32-bit dll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error loading DLL in python, not a valid win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849077/error-loading-dll-in-python-not-a-valid-win32-application)

Answer (score 25):

Mentioning [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) (although this doesn't have very much to do with it) just in case.

The underlying error is ***ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT*** (*193*, *0xC1*). Check it in [[MS.Docs]: System Error Codes (0-499)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). It's a **general *Win* error** (not related to *Python*). In the current case (related to *Python*), the exception is a (*Python*) wrapper over it.

#### 1. The error

The error message is confusing (especially because of ***%1*** placeholder). For more details on that, check [[SO]: Why is %1 rarely substituted in “%1 is not a valid Win32 application.”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43615129/4788546).

This error occurs when *Win* tries to load what it thinks it's an executable (*PE*) image (*.exe*, *.dll*, ...), but it actually isn't. There's a variety of situations when this is encountered (*Google*ing the error, would yield lots of results).

There are a bunch of possible reasons for this to happen when the image is loaded from a file (existing and readable, otherwise the error would differ - **look at one of the bullets at the answer end**):

- Was downloaded and the download is incomplete
- Was (mistakenly) overwritten (or messed up with)
- Is corrupt because of filesystem problem
- Many many more

2 main usecases lead to this error:

1. Attempting to run a file which is not an *.exe* ([[SO]: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25651990/4788546))
2. Trying to load a *.dll* in a process (running *.exe*). **This is the one that I'm going to focus on**

Below, it's an example of a dummy executable attempting to load a *.dll* (might want to check [[SO]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469099/4788546) for details on command line build on *Win*).

*main00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{
    DWORD gle = 0;
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibraryA(".\\dll00.dll");
    if (hMod == NULL) {
        gle = GetLastError();
        printf("LoadLibrary failed: %d (0x%08X)\n", gle, gle);
    } else {
        FreeLibrary(hMod);
    }
    return gle;
}
```

**Output**:

- **Note**: I'll be reusing this *cmd* console, even if the copy / paste snippets will be scattered across the answer

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057187566]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> :: Build for 064bit (pc064)
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00_v0.c
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo main00.c  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main00_064.exe
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> :: Creating an invalid .dll
> [prompt]> echo garbage> dll00.dll
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.dll
> dll00_v0.c
> main00.c
> main00.obj
> main00_064.exe
>
> [prompt]> main00_064.exe
> LoadLibrary failed: 193 (0x000000C1)
> ```

As seen, I created a file *dll00.dll* containing the text "*garbage*", so it's a *.dll* file with invalid contents.

The most common case for this error, is an architecture mismatch:

- ***064bit* process attempting to load a *032bit* *.dll***
- ***032bit* process attempting to load a *064bit* *.dll***

In any of the above 2 cases, even if the *.dll* contains a valid image (for a different architecture), it's still invalid from the current process *PoV*. For things to run *OK*, **the 2 involved *CPU* architectures must match** <sup>***(1)***</sup>.

#### 2. *Python* context

*CTypes* does the same thing when loading a *.dll*: it calls [[MS.Docs]: LoadLibraryW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw) on the *.dll* name. 
So this is the exact same case for the *Python* process where *CTypes* tries to load the *.dll* in.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import os
import sys


DLL_BASE_NAME = "dll00"


def main(*argv):
    dll_name = os.path.join(
        os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
        (argv[0] if argv else DLL_BASE_NAME) + (".dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else ".so"))
    print("Attempting to load: [{:s}]".format(dll_name))
    dll00 = cts.CDLL(dll_name)
    func00 = dll00.dll00Func00
    func00.argtypes = ()
    func00.restype = cts.c_int

    res = func00()
    print("{:s} returned {:d}".format(func00.__name__, res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Note**: check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions).

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> :: dll00.dll still contains garbage
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Attempting to load: [e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057187566\dll00.dll]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 25, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "code00.py", line 14, in main
>     dll00 = ct.CDLL(dll_name)
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.09\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
> ```

Here's an example for ***(#1)*** <sup>(from above)</sup>, which attempts all 4 combinations.

*dll00_v0.c*:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


DLL00_EXPORT_API size_t dll00Func00()
{
    return sizeof(void*);
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> :: Still building for pc064 from previous vcvarsall call
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL dll00_v0.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00_064.dll
> dll00_v0.c
>    Creating library dll00_064.lib and object dll00_064.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Build for 032bit (pc032)
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.40
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL dll00_v0.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00_032.dll
> dll00_v0.c
>    Creating library dll00_032.lib and object dll00_032.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b *.dll
> dll00.dll
> dll00_032.dll
> dll00_064.dll
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Python pc064
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dll00_064
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Attempting to load: [e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057187566\dll00_064.dll]
> dll00Func00 returned 8
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dll00_032
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Attempting to load: [e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057187566\dll00_032.dll]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 25, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "code00.py", line 14, in main
>     dll00 = ct.CDLL(dll_name)
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.09\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Python pc032
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.07.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dll00_032
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:01:55) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] 032bit on win32
>
> Attempting to load: [e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057187566\dll00_032.dll]
> dll00Func00 returned 4
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.07.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dll00_064
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:01:55) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] 032bit on win32
>
> Attempting to load: [e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057187566\dll00_064.dll]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 25, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "code00.py", line 14, in main
>     dll00 = ct.CDLL(dll_name)
>   File "c:\Install\pc032\Python\Python\03.07.09\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
> ```

#### 3. Bonus

In the above examples, the *.dll* was loaded "on demand" by explicitly calling *LoadLibrary* (or *LoadLibraryEx*). 
The other case is when a *.exe* or *.dll* depends on (was linked against) another *.dll*, and loads it automatically when itself is being loaded (although I'm almost certain that *LoadLibrary* - or maybe a lower level function - is automatically called under the hood on the dependent *.dll*). 
In the example below, *dll00*.dll* depends on *dll01*.dll*. 
Only exemplifying for *032bit* (as this is the current build environment set by previous operation).

- *dll01.h*:

  ```c
  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  if defined(DLL01_EXPORTS)
  #    define DLL01_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #  else
  #    define DLL01_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #  endif
  #else
  #  define DLL01_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  DLL01_EXPORT_API void dll01Func00();
  ```
- *dll01.c*:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define DLL01_EXPORTS
  #include "dll01.h"


  void dll01Func00()
  {
      printf("In [%s]\n", __FUNCTION__);
  }
  ```
- *dll00_v1.c*: (modified *dll00_v0.c*):

  ```c
  #include <inttypes.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif

  #include "dll01.h"


  DLL00_EXPORT_API size_t dll00Func00()
  {
      dll01Func00();
      return sizeof(void*);
  }
  ```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> :: Still building for pc032 from previous vcvarsall call
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL dll01.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll01_032.dll
> dll01.c
>    Creating library dll01_032.lib and object dll01_032.exp
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL dll00_v1.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00_032.dll
> dll00_v1.c
>    Creating library dll00_032.lib and object dll00_032.exp
> dll00_v1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__dll01Func00 referenced in function _dll00Func00
> dll00_032.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL dll00_v1.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00_032.dll dll01_032.lib
> dll00_v1.c
>    Creating library dll00_032.lib and object dll00_032.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.07.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dll00_032
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:01:55) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] 032bit on win32
>
> Attempting to load: [e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057187566\dll00_032.dll]
> In [dll01Func00]
> dll00Func00 returned 4
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> :: Messing up dll01_032.dll
> [prompt]> echo garbage> dll01_032.dll
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.07.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dll00_032
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:01:55) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] 032bit on win32
>
> Attempting to load: [e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057187566\dll00_032.dll]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 25, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "code00.py", line 14, in main
>     dll00 = ct.CDLL(dll_name)
>   File "c:\Install\pc032\Python\Python\03.07.09\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
> ```

**Stating the obvious**: Same error would occur if instead of writing garbage data into *dll01_032.dll*, I would have build it for *064bit*, but I chose this variant as it's shorter.

#### 4. Conclusions

Everything that I'll state in each of the next bullets, also applies to the ones that follow it.

- In the examples above, the error occurred when the corruption was in the very *.dll* being loaded, or in one of its direct dependents (level 1 of indirection). It's not hard to figure out that applying the same principle multiple times, the behavior wouldn't change, so it's valid for any level of indirection. 
  Imagine a *.dll* that depends on several other *.dll*s, and each of those depends in turn on several others, and so on ... . That is called a **dependency tree**. So no matter **where in the tree this error will occur, it will be propagated up to the root node** (which is the *.dll*)
- The dependency tree propagation applies to other errors as well. Another one that it's **widely encountered** is ***ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND*** (*126*, *0x7E*). It means that the *.dll* with the specified name (**restating: or any other *.dll* that it (recursively) depends on**) was not found. Check [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546) for more details on the topic (also in *Python* context). 
  As a side note, in order to check a *.dll* (or *.exe*) dependencies, check [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546), or as a matter of fact, use any tool capable of getting *PE* dependency information
- Everything discussed also applies:

  - **When importing an extension module** (***.pyd*** (*.so* on *Nix*)). That's right, the *.pyd* is just a *.dll* (which exports a *PyInit_** function). Check [[Python.Docs]: Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c) for more details
  - If the *.dll* is being loaded as a result of another module (*.pyd*, *.py*, ...) being imported
- Everything discussed also applies to *Nix* systems, the errors (and corresponding messages), obviously differ

#### 5. Summarizing

Make sure that:

- A *064bit* process **only attempts to load** *064bit* *.dll*s
- A *032bit* process **only attempts to load** *032bit* *.dll*s

otherwise, ending up in this (nasty) situation is (almost) certain.

Some real life scenario steps leading here:

1. Installing a software (*Python* - in this case)
2. Installing (creating, building) some kind of plugin (that contains *.dll*s) for that software (*an (extension) module* - in this case)

Although in general this kind of check is performed at install time, one needs to check (as already stated), that the *CPU* architectures of the (above) 2, **must match**. 
If that doesn't happen, **change one to match the other**, and whenever possible (as there might be some (few) cases when it isn't), **aim for 064bit** (as it doesn't have many of *032bit*'s limitations).
In this case, **install (and run) *Python 064bit*** ([[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053286/4788546)).

Comment: This is about as authoritative as it gets. Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 4):

As @CristiFati stated this is occuring because

1)64bit process attempting to load a 32bit .dll

2)32bit process attempting to load a 64bit .dll

Solution:

--> I also encountered the same problem and noticed that my gcc compiler was producing 32-bit compiled files instead of 64-bit.So I changed the compiler which produces 64-bit files.

--> you can check your  compiled file(.exe) is 64 or 32 bit by  -->right click --> properties--> compatablity -->check the compatibilty mode option-->select the dropdown if you see windows xp in the list then your compiler is producing 32-bit files if you dont see windows xp then your compiler is producing 64-bit files.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little assurance for what it is worth, I too encountered this same problem but thought I had 32 bit versions of everything installed on Win10 64, and if true, the answer wouldn't apply to my circumstance. However, in checking I discovered I was using mingw32 bit on the C side of the equation and a 64 bit on the Python side. I installed Python version 32.10.6, and voila, everything worked. So, to second Manoj D Bhat, @CristiFati's last statement was correct in my case - usual cause of error is either:

1)64 bit process attempting to load a 32 bit .dll

or

2)32 bit process attempting to load a 64 bit .dll

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the detailed explanation.

But for those who wanted a direct solution.
I think you should set up 64-bit python version and the issue will be resolved. It worked for me.