# import pjsua: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python-2.7, pjsua2

When i try to `import pjsua` it's showing below error in windows python x64 bit

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File stdin, line 1, in 
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I'm using Python 2.7 and these are for pjsua build generation.When i search for this issue some one asked to install opencv and set the env path.I tried it but no luck.

Please help us to solve this.

I'm referring https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Build_Install.

Comment: any idea about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-multidimensional-arrays-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-1/57297745#57297745. Your *pjsua* and *Python* architectures don't match. One is *32bit* while the other is *64bit*. They have to be the same if you want to use them together.

Comment: You might also want to check https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PJSUA2.