# Python 64 bit on windows: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing

Tags: python, 64-bit

For a long time I'm using a 32-bit python interpreter without a problem. Lately I installed a 64-bit interpreter and installed Anaconda which python has the following info:

Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

When I try to run some code for example
'Import pandas as pd' then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sveno\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\sveno\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\sveno\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\sveno\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing
```

Deleting the 32-bit version does not solve the problem

Comment: The error is because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745. But I think you have a messed up *%PYTHONPATH%*.

Comment: Do you mean my path is incorrect?
I have two paths for python:

C:\Users\sveno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\
C:\Users\sveno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\

How could I solve this problem?