# Trying to use matplotlib, but getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using Python 3.7.5 + PyCharm 2018 Edition
The following shows what I get in the console at startup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Проект ДО ЧЕТВЕРГА!/тест либы yandex.translate.py", line 3, in <module>
      import matplotlib
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
      from . import cbook, rcsetup
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
      import numpy as np
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
      from . import _distributor_init
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
      WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
File "C:\Python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
      self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code I am trying to run:

```
datelist =  ['2014-05-06', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-08', '2014-05-09', '2014-05-10',    '2014-05-11', '2014-05-12', '2014-05-13']

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import dates
import datetime

converted_dates = list(map(datetime.datetime.strptime, datelist, len(datelist)*['%Y-%m-%d']))
x_axis = converted_dates
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')


y_axis = range(0,8)
pyplot.plot( x_axis, y_axis, '-' )
ax = pyplot.gcf().axes[0]
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
pyplot.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=25)
pyplot.show()
```

Would be extremely glad if you help me find the error and help correct it.

Comment: Seems your matplotlib installation is either broken or not the correct one for your system.

Comment: Most likely, architecture mismatch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745.

Comment: I tried to reinstall this module three times, but the error does not disappear

Comment: Update PyCharm.  There are known issues.

Comment: What *Python* version are you using? Do you have both *Python* *64bit* and *32bit* installed? What *Python* is *PyCharm* invoking? How did you install the "faulty" modules?

Answer (score -1):

I have installed unofficial builds of these libraries. The error disappeared