# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application ( is that related with the version?)

Tags: python, ctypes

I wanna just use the C++ module. (or C), but when i try to import the *.dll* file, I always see the error.

I am just typing

**test.ipynb**

```
from ctypes import *
       mydll=windll.LoadLibrary "D:\\MyLab\\Python\\C++connect\\ddltest.dll")
```

- My anaconda is 64bit.
- Windows also is 64bit.

How can i solve this problem?

My full error message is this.

> ---
>
> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 mydll = windll.LoadLibrary("D:\MyLab\Python\C++connect\ddltest.dll")
>
> D:\anaconda\envs\bigdata-platform\lib\ctypes__init__.py in
>   LoadLibrary(self, name)
>       432 
>       433     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
>   --> 434         return self._dlltype(name)
>       435 
>       436 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)
>
> D:\anaconda\envs\bigdata-platform\lib\ctypes__init__.py in
>   **init**(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
>       354 
>       355         if handle is None:
>   --> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>       357         else:
>       358             self._handle = handle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745

Answer (score 1):

DLL's have to match the bit-ness of the executable, in this case the Python executable. Loading a 32 bits DLL in a 64 bit Python will fail as described, with a 193 error.

64 bit versions of Windows can still run 32 bits executables, because these Windows versions have two set of the system DLL's.