# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application while reading custom DLL in python with CTypes

Tags: python, c, windows, ctypes

I am trying to write code that wraps a C library in python. I am planning on using CTypes to do it and I used visual studio to compile my DLL. I started with a simple function and I added the following in a header within Visual Studio that was then built to a DLL

```
int our_function(int num_numbers, int* numbers) {
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < num_numbers; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

My python wrapper is the following

```
import ctypes

_sum = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Users\spl\Desktop\Ctypes Testing\Ctypes tester 2.dll")
_sum.our_function.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))

def our_function(numbers):
    global _sum
    num_numbers = len(numbers)
    array_type = ctypes.c_int * num_numbers
    result = _sum.our_function(ctypes.c_int(num_numbers), array_type(*numbers))
    return int(result)

print(sum.our_function([1,2,-3,4,-5,6]))
```

When I execute the python code I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sum.py", line 3, in <module>
    _sum = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Users\spl\Desktop\Ctypes Testing\Ctypes tester 2.dll")
  File "C:\Users\spl\anaconda3\envs\Blank tester\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What causes this error and how do I fix it? I am using a 64 bit machine with windows 10 and my python build is 64 bit. I don't know much C, and the main goal is to get it working so that I can code everything in python.

Comment: Please provide a hex dump of the first 512 bytes or so of `C:\Users\spl\Desktop\Ctypes Testing\Ctypes tester 2.dll`.  (Do this by editing your question.  Did you know you can edit your question?  The tiny gray word "edit" under the tags is a button.  Yes, it's bad UI design.  Sorry about that.)

Comment: It would also be interesting to know what happens if you call [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) on this DLL from a C++ program compiled by the same copy of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical ***CPU* architecture** (*032bit* (your *.dll*) *vs.* *064bit* (*Python* process that tries to load it)) **mismatch**. Check [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) for more details.

Build the *064bit* (*pc064*) version of your your *.dll*. 
You can use the command line tools from the aforementioned *URL*, or you can set the *VStudio IDE* to do it, as explained in [[MS.Docs]: How to: Configure Visual Studio C++ projects to Target 64-Bit, x64 Platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-configure-visual-cpp-projects-to-target-64-bit-platforms):

> 1. Open the C++ project that you want to configure.
> 2. Open the property pages for that project. For more information, see [Set C++ compiler and build properties in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019).
> 3. Choose the **Configuration Manager** button to open the **Configuration Manager** dialog box.
> 4. In the **Active Solution Platform** drop-down list, select the **<New...>** option to open the **New Solution Platform** dialog box.
> 5. In the **Type or select the new platform** drop-down list, select a 64-bit target platform.
> 6. Choose the **OK** button. The platform that you selected in the preceding step appears under **Active Solution Platform** in the **Configuration Manager** dialog box.
> 7. Choose the **Close** button in the **Configuration Manager** dialog box, and then choose the **OK** button in the **<Projectname> Property Pages** dialog box.