# windows DLL is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: windows, dll, java-native-interface, loadlibrary

### overview

The same dll(tableOcr.dll) in different system win10s(win10 family series and win10 professional series ) behave different result.

### build tool

```
  1. java 
  2. corretto-1.8.0_302 
     openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
     OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.302.08.1 (build 1.8.0_302-b08)
     OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.302.08.1 (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)
  3. c++11
  4. visual studio 2017 (14.9)
```

### background

I need java(x64) call my c++ func through jni, my shared library is tableOcr.dll(x64) and tableOcrJni.dll(x64) which links to tableOcr.dll; I did those steps:

1. build my tableOcr.dll(x64) with visual studio 2017 (14.9), windows SDk version  10.0.17763.0 in win10 professional(x64 version=10.0.18363.1440) .
   TableOcrJNI.dll denpentent is tableOcr.dll,lickey_parse.dll and opencv_world430.dll(checked by x64 depend.exe)
   One of tableOcrJNI.dll function is :

```
#ifndef OCREXPORT
# if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#   if defined(STATIC_LINKED)
#     define OCR_EXPORT
#   else
#     define OCR_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport) ///！ 为了动态加载动态库
//#     define OCR_EXPORT  ///！ 为了动态加载动态库
#   endif
# else
#   if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(GCC_HASCLASSVISIBILITY)
#     define OCR_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#   else
#     define OCR_EXPORT
#   endif
# endif
#endif
```

`OCR_EXPORT int  _cdecl obtain_table_info_init(const char* _IN_ models`

2. Use a test.exe(build on x64 professional win10) test win32 loadLibrary way to load tableOcrJni.dll. this dll loaded with absolute path.

   **It success**.
3. Use java test program load my tableOcrJni.dll, it result in is not valid win32 IN windows 10 family series (x64 version=10.19043.1706)

### addition

:

1. I'm pretty sure %PATH% is OK for my java, I add my dlls(all linked dlls) path `E:/mydll/` in It.
2. I tried some solution found in google(included this palce), not helped.
3. I tried step 3 in  win10 professional(x64 version=10.0.18363.1440) series(), it is OK.
4. I tried install vs 2017 on win10 family serial,and do step
   all failed.
5. I tried build x64 corretto-1.8.0_302 jdk on x64 win10 family and do step3, failed.

Comment: DependencyWalker.com

Comment: It's unclear to me what errors or exceptions you are getting. Please include details like this in the body of the question.

Comment: @Anders I tried before I met this problem, DependencyWalker helped nothing, I checked the cpu type, checked deep linked libraries, all is fine.

Comment: @clvrmnky, sorry about that, the key is my dll cant run ok in win10 family series but win10 profissonal series

Answer (score 0):

It's a ***CPU* architecture (bitness) mismatch** between *Java* (the executable) and your *.dll* (*pc064* <=> *pc032* or viceversa). Check [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) for more details on the topic.

To check *Java* architecture use:

```bat
[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q072210792]> java -version
java version "1.8.0_331"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_331-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.331-b09, mixed mode)
```

In my case it's *pc064* (*064bit*).

You have 2 options:

- Build your *.dll* to match *Java*'s architecture ([[SO]: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application while reading custom DLL in python with CTypes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733777/4788546))
- Install the *Java* version (if available) that matches your *.dll*'s

Since I don't know which is which, my advice is to move towards *pc064*.

In order to check *PE*s bitness, dependencies, and many more details, you could use [[GitHub]: lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), or (older) [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com), or (*VStudio*'s) *DumpBin* ([[MS.Docs]: DUMPBIN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference)).

Comment: No, first doubt when I met this question is the  mismatch. but I got wrong , I edited the question infomation. the question key is the same x64 dll  loadlibrarys dirffent result

Comment: It's not easy for me to understand all the steps you did, but the error cause is the one that I explained.

Comment: Still kind of confusing to me (when I deal with this kinds of situations I change one thing at a time to isolate the problem sooner), but *java.exe* seems to be *032bit*. Or there are other *.dll*s with the same name and those get picked instead yours.

Answer (score 0):

It is link styple mismatch. My tableOcrJni.dll behaves same as tableOcr.dll. So I just need try anything against tableOcr.dll. TableOcr.dll link some dlls like I said, So I put tableOcr.dll to `E:/mydll`, put tableOcr.dll's dynamic link dlls to `E:/mydllDepend`, activate ENV after that. It works in Win10 x64 family series !!!! but no prove has been found that I must do that way.