# How can I make ctypes.util.find_library() find the correct .dll?

Tags: python, dll, path, sdk, ctypes

I've been trying to install the [Picoscope SDK python wrapper](https://github.com/picotech/picosdk-python-wrappers) onto my Windows 10 computer. I've installed the SDK but also the Picoscope6 application.

The *setup.py* and the wrapper class called *Library* uses the *ctypes.util.find_library()* to locate *'ps2000.dll'* on my system.

There is a *'ps2000.dll'* in the folder (Which I've added to my system environment path):

*C:\Program Files\Pico Technology\SDK\lib*

But there's also a *'PS2000.dll'* in the folder (notice that this file is in upper-case):

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Pico Technology\PicoScope6*

Both python scripts needs the path to the first one, but ctypes.util.find_library('ps2000') returns the path to the second one.

```
>>> from ctypes.util import find_library
>>> find_library('ps2000')
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pico Technology\\PicoScope6\\ps2000.dll'
```

I have another machine where this is not the case.

I was wondering what I would have to change, to make *ctypes.util.find_library('ps2000')* return the correct path.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

The upper / lower case is not relevant, *Win* *FS* is **case insensitive**.

The behavior you're experiencing is due to [[MS.Learn]: File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Long story short: your *032bit* (*pc032*) *Python* finds the *pc032* *ps2000.dll* (or *PS2000.DLL* - same thing), but you need the *064bit* (*pc064*) version of the *.dll*. In that case you should install (and use) ***pc064* *Python***.

References:

- [[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053286/4788546)
- [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546)
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)