# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application in CTypes

Tags: python, anaconda, ctypes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use CTypes to call a C function from Python, but keep getting this error: `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.  I'm using the WSL to compile the C file into a .so file using this command: `gcc -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so test.c` and have this Python code:

```
from ctypes import *


lib = CDLL('./libtest.so')
print(lib.square(5))
```

I can run the Python file using the WSL, but I can't run it using an Anaconda environment from PyCharm.  I'm guessing the error is due to the C object being created in the WSL.  Is there a way to fix the error and make it so I can compile the C files on the WSL and use the compiled object files in an Anaconda environment?

Comment: That error is typically due to mixing 32-bit and 64-bit EXE/DLL files.  If using 64-bit Python, the DLL needs to be 64-bit.  Likewise 32-bit Python must use a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745).  But in your case it's not this. ***WSL* is an *Ubuntu 20*, and binaries are not compatible with *Win***! You should build your code for *Win* (use *VStudio*,  or if you want to build it on *Nix*, use some cross toolchain (*MinGW32*) - but this would be an overcomplication).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with ctypes. In my case, the problem was with the `'.so'` files, so I followed this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) to create `'.dll'` files.
Then the rest of the python code remains the same, except `'./libtest.so' -> './libtest.dll'`