# having both mingw32 and mingw64 in path - is it ok?

Tags: windows, dll, environment, mingw-w64, mingw32

quick question: is it safe to have both ming32 and ming64 runtimes in path?

As they are 32 vs. 64 I would guess dlls would not clash and properly resolved in both cased, but maybe I am missing something.

FYI: It works in fact on my computer, I am just not sure about the theory.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is simple, *Win* will attempt to locate:

- Executables (when not launched with full path)
- *DLL*s (loaded (recursively) by executables)

in the directories from *%PATH%* **in the order that they appear**.

References:

- [[SS64]: How-to: Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) (a quick browse didn't reveal a "more official" resource)
- [[MS.Docs]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

A *MinGW* version is stand alone (it doesn't depend on the other), so if all its *dir*s are in *%PATH%*, it will be chosen automatically, and the 2<sup>nd</sup> version is simply going be ignored therefore its presence in *%PATH%* is useless (actually, it will add additional overhead when the *OS* will search those *dir*s too). 
**However**, if *dir*s from the 2 versions are inserted interleavedly (some *dir*s from 1<sup>st</sup> version, some from 2<sup>nd</sup> version, some other *dir*s from 1<sup>st</sup> version, ...), then you might (and most likely will) get in trouble, so **don't do it**.

I guess you need both variants to generate *064bit* and *032bit* binaries.
But doesn't *GCC*'s ***-m32*** argument do the trick?

In short: there are some situations when it's *OK* (to have both versions in *%PATH%*), there are others when it's not. But, in any case, having the 2<sup>nd</sup> version will come with **no** benefit.

On a related topic, check [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745) for details about mixing processes and *.dll*s built for different architectures.

Comment: that's exactly what I though first - but then: 64bit and 32bit dlls are incompatible as they cannot be used in the same process - hence the 64 bit binary will ignore the available 32 bit dlls even if they are first in the path, and vica versa, wont they? that's actually what I am curious about

Comment: When it will find one, it will attempt to load it. In case of failure, it won't try to load it from somewhere else (search subsequent *dir*s), but it will throw an error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745).

Comment: thanks for clarification - yep seems it fails when name matches but wordsize does not. so I guess I am just lucky I that specific case