# How can i run this code in Python 3.9 (64-bit)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, 64-bit, ctypes

When I run the code I get this error:

`[WinError 193]% 1 is not a valid Win32 application`

```
    from ctypes import *
    mydll = windll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll")
    mydll.Beep(2000,500)
```

Comment: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745). You have *064bit* *Python* trying to open a *032bit* *.dll*. Use *r"C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll"* or simply *r"kernel32.dll"*.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Use `dll = WinDLL('kernel32')`. That path is in the default DLL search path.

You have to use 32-bit DLLs with 32-bit Python and 64-bit DLLs with 64-bit Python.

Non-intuitively, `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` on 64-bit Windows contains DLLs compatible with 32-bit applications and `C:\Windows\System32` contains 64-bit DLLs.

However, whether you are using 32-bit Python or 64-bit Python, always use `C:\Windows\System32` if hard-coding the path because for backward compatibility, 32-bit applications originally written for 32-bit Windows will try to open `C:\Windows\System32` but if run on 64-bit Windows will automatically redirect the access to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.