# Lua "module 'socket.core' not found"

Tags: windows, sockets, dll, module, lua

I'm Trying to import sockets in a lua script to make a twitch chat app inside a game.
The game implementation of lua is "Designed to work with OpenResty’s fork of LuaJIT, with LuaJIT compiled with 5.2 compatibility option." (https://github.com/ac-custom-shaders-patch/acc-lua-sdk/)

I am not familiar with lua but I have been trying to get this to work for a few days but with not much progress.
I have tried different repositories with sockets/websockets but could not get them to work.

when trying `local socket = require("socket")` I get the following error

[

```
module 'socket.core' not found: no field package.preload['socket.core'] 
no file '\socket\core.lua' 
no file 'E:\steam\SteamApps\common\assettocorsa\ua\socket\core.lua' 
no file 'E:\steam\SteamApps\common\assettocorsa\Jua\socket\core\init.lua' 
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\Jua\socket\core.luac' 
no file 'E:\steam\SteamApps\common\assettocorsa\apps\lua\My FirstApp/socket\core.lua' 
no file 'E:\steam\SteamApps\common\assettocorsa\extension/internal/lua-socket\core.lua' 
no file '\socket\core.dil' 
no file 'E:\steam\SteamApps\common\assettocorsa\socket\core.dil' 
no file 'E:\steam\SteamApps\common\assettocorsa\Vloadall.dll' 
no file '.\socket.dll' 
no file 'E:\steam\SteamApps\common\assettocorsa\socket.dll' 
no file 'E:\steam\SteamApps\common\assettocorsa\loadall.dll' [C]: in function 'require 
...mApps\common\assettocorsa\apps\lua\My FirstApp/socket.lua:12: in main chunk [C]: in function 'require' 
...s\common\assettocorsa\apps\lua\My FirstApp\MyFirstApp.lua:13: in main chunk
```

][1]

If I understood this correctly that socket.core is normally something included in the lua language that would be installed on the machine. But I need this to be included with the app so it can be shared to other people as well.

From my understanding I need something made for lua 5.1 and compiled for windows. The game runs in 64bits by default but can be forced to 32 bits so i'm assuming ideally i'd need 2 dlls.

This is mostly why I've been trying hard to get this particular solution (https://github.com/luapower/socket) to work as they include pre build dlls which I'm assuming contain everything needed for socket to run. But I can't get the error above to go away.

I have also not been able to build my own dll due to my lack of understanding of lua and programming in general and more importantly i'm not sure what to build exactly to make sure it would work for this particular usecase.

The whole lua stuff seems to be super unfriendly to use on windows in general which only adds to my confusion so any insight on how I could proceed to get this to work would be greatly appreciated. I can supply further info neeeded.

edit: it seems that my understanding of where require was looking for files was wrong. I've moved the files to a separate folder and I now get `Error: error loading module socket.core' from file '.\socket\core.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. [C]: at 0x7ffd961fb3c0 [C]: in function 'require' ...s\common\assettocorsa\apps\lua\MyFirstApp\MyFirstApp.lua:16: in main chunk`

So I guess it's running lua in 32 bits? I tried to grab some compiled socket/core.dll from diff repos and they all give the error.. I checked with dependency walker and some were 32 bits and others were 64bits dlls. Same error regardless.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdexh.png

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are no commits in [[GitHub]: luapower/socket](https://github.com/luapower/socket) since *Nov 2019*. Also, the directory structure doesn't seem correct. And (something that should have been mentioned there) it was built (and runs) with *Lua 5.1*.

I've built *v3.0.0* and placed the binaries at: [[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/LuaSocket/v3](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/LuaSocket/v3) (**built with *Lua 5.4.4* from the same repository**, which should be used to run it).

Here's an example:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q071876058]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\lua.exe" -l socket
> c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\lua.exe: module 'socket' not found:
>         no field package.preload['socket']
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\lua\socket.lua'
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\lua\socket\init.lua'
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\socket.lua'
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\socket\init.lua'
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\..\share\lua\5.4\socket.lua'
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\..\share\lua\5.4\socket\init.lua'
>         no file '.\socket.lua'
>         no file '.\socket\init.lua'
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\socket.dll'
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\..\lib\lua\5.4\socket.dll'
>         no file 'c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\loadall.dll'
>         no file '.\socket.dll'
> stack traceback:
>         [C]: in function 'require'
>         [C]: in ?
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> set LUA_PATH=;;c:\Program Files\LunarModules\LuaSocket\3.0.0(Lua5.4)\?.lua
>
> [prompt]> set LUA_CPATH=;;c:\Program Files\LunarModules\LuaSocket\3.0.0(Lua5.4)\?.dll
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "c:\Program Files\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\lua.exe" -l socket
> Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> > -- Lua started, meaning the module was successfully loaded
> > ^Z
>
>
> [prompt]> :: Attempt to load the module in Lua 32bit (pc032)
> [prompt]> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\lua.exe" -l socket
> c:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\Lua\5.4.4\bin\lua.exe: error loading module 'socket.core' from file 'c:\Program Files\LunarModules\LuaSocket\3.0.0(Lua5.4)\socket\core.dll':
>         %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>
> stack traceback:
>         [C]: in ?
>         [C]: in function 'require'
>         ...am Files\LunarModules\LuaSocket\3.0.0(Lua5.4)\socket.lua:12: in main chunk
>         [C]: in function 'require'
>         [C]: in ?
>
> [prompt]> :: Module structure
> [prompt]> tree /a /f "c:\Program Files\LunarModules\LuaSocket\3.0.0(Lua5.4)"
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WIN
> Volume serial number is 0000001F F2CE:FA29
> C:\PROGRAM FILES\LUNARMODULES\LUASOCKET\3.0.0(LUA5.4)
> |   ltn12.lua
> |   LuaSocket.LICENSE
> |   mbox.lua
> |   mime.lua
> |   socket.lua
> |
> +---mime
> |       core.dll
> |
> \---socket
>         core.dll
>         ftp.lua
>         headers.lua
>         http.lua
>         smtp.lua
>         tp.lua
>         url.lua
> ```

As seen, I also covered the *pc064* / *pc032* *.dll* mismatch. For more details, check [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745).

Comment: @Ligneel: Did you have the chance to give it a try?