# pyzkaccess python library gives this error OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python

i am following this [documentation](https://bdragon300.github.io/pyzkaccess/)
but i cannot get anything to work
as the documentation suggests, i installed pyzkaccess, installed the pull SDK and copied the dll files to the system directory
if i run the code under "quick start" from the documentation i get this error

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

this is the code im trying to run

```
from pyzkaccess import ZKAccess

connstr = 'protocol=TCP,ipaddress=192.168.1.201,port=4370,timeout=4000,passwd='
zk = ZKAccess(connstr=connstr)
print('Device SN:', zk.parameters.serial_number, 'IP:', zk.parameters.ip_address)

# Turn on relays in "lock" group for 5 seconds
zk.relays.lock.switch_on(5)

# Wait for any card will appear on reader of Door 1
card = None
while not card:
    for door1_event in zk.doors[0].events.poll(timeout=60):
        print(door1_event)
        if door1_event.card and door1_event.card != '0':
            print('Got card #', door1_event.card)
            card = door1_event.card

# Switch on both relays on door 1
zk.doors[0].relays.switch_on(5)

# After that restart a device
zk.restart()
zk.disconnect()
```

i have no idea what could be causing this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win)

Comment: docs say the SDK ships 32bit dll's -- i'd assume that is the root cause if your python is 64bit version ..

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue.
It needs 32 bit windows.
I recommend to use Windows 10 32bit, because you can't install latest python version on windows 7 or earlier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).