# Ctypes - C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

> I'm attempting to use ctypes to integrate C++ functions into my Python project, but I'm encountering an error as soon as I try to load the C++ library with ctypes.CDLL. The error message I'm receiving is: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I've already verified that the library file exists (compiled with the command: `g++ -fPIC -shared -o main00.so main00.cpp`)and is located in the correct directory. My Python environment is on a Windows system. Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how I can resolve it to successfully use C++ functions in Python using ctypes?

*main00.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

*main00.py*

```
import ctypes   
cf = ctypes.CDLL(r"main00.so")
```

Comment: first, name your lib .dll not .so, then check if compiler is the same architecture as python (32/32 bits or 64/64 bits)

Comment: Are you running `g++` in [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)?

Comment: I'm running g++ inside vs code terminal in a windows system

Comment: Running `g++ -v` I got `--build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`. Also Python is 64 bits.

Comment: So you're building your library inside of WSL, but trying to use it in Windows outside of WSL?

Comment: **[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**. Post your build commands, run commands and other details in the question. Also: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546).