# I want to import all the functions in C program from Python. I got OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, c, linux, dll, ctypes

c file; Lets say **func.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int display(char* str, int age) {
    printf("Name %s age is %d",str,age);
    return 0;
}
```

**In command prompt**: gcc -fPIC -shared -o func.so func.c
To convert c file to .so, so that it could be called by libraries like ctypes, cffi, etc..

**main.py**

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
clibrary = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Users\Desktop\func.so")
clibrary.display(b"hi", 22)
```

While I am running main.py, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    clibrary = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Users\Desktop\func.so")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
**OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application**
```

I am expecting to resolve the error `your text`

Comment: You're building for *Nix* and try to load it in *Win* *Python*? ?It's not going to work. Ore you're using an emulator (*MinGW*, *MSYS2*, *Cygwin*, ...)? Duplicate of [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546)?

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for that. I have installed 32bit Python and it is working fine.